# Using angular-dart components, supply own instances instead of calling the constructor

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In angular-dart it is possible to create your own components as can be seen [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki/Increasing-code-reuse-through-Components). If you use custom tags in the html like this:

```html
<rating></rating>
```

angular will create a component by calling the constructor of the class associated with rating, in this case new RatingComponent() (if i'm not mistaken).

I know you can add attributes for having some control over it, but i was wondering if it is possible to supply your own instances, instead of angular calling the constructor. What if i have a list of buttons in the main controller, how to achieve something like this:

```html
<div ng-repeat='b in ctrl.buttonList'>
    <fancy-button instance='b'></fancy-button>
</div>
```

I have the feeling i'm missing something obvious, but i did search around and couldn't find the answer.

**edit** (for extra clarification): I think it boils down to if you can or can not influence/bypass the call of the constructor by angular. If it was just about generating the html, its easy to not use the component and just generate the html using the main-controller (like below), but if possible i would like to use a component since it also has shadow-dom for sandboxing the css.

```html
<div ng-repeat='b in ctrl.buttonList'>
    <input type='button' class='fancy' value='{{b.label}}'></input>
</div>
```

Comment: The class responsible for fancy-button could check the `instance` attribute and do a `switch` over its value and do different things. As another possibility, you (maybe) could declare a component that triggers on specific values of the instance attribute. `@NgComponent('selector':'fancy-button[instance=unicorn]', …) class MyUnicornButton { … }` (link to (java;(doc  http://goo.gl/j0tYCg) and have the angular processor sort it out through reflection. If this is sort of what you have on mind and if you are interested, I can try this out and post examples if something of it works.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```html
<div ng-bind-html='ctrl.html'></div>
```

This way you can provide the html by the controller.

You would have to create your own implementation of NgBindHtmlDirective (just a few lines) though, because the used NodeValidator of ng-bind-html doesn't allow custom tags (yet).

Maybe there are more sophisticated ways but I don't know Angular very well yet.

=== Edit ===

I think what you try to do is not Angularish.
You can ng-repeat over a model that provides values for the attributes of the fancy-button or input.
In the components class you have access to these attributes and can make the behavior and appearance depending on that attributes.

Using ng-bind-html you can create the markup using code if you don't know at development time what kind of tag you want to use.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand you, but _instance_ is something i made up to make my intention clear. Afaik there is no such attribute to prevent angular from calling the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, the first answer didn't fit to the question.

I have edited the answer. 
There are probably better ways to do this though.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt anyway. I'm specifically looking for a way to bypass the call to the constructor. If that is not possible, i was thinking about supplying angular an argument to use on a factory constructor. Then the factory constructor could just return the argument itself. But this is a very ugly solution of course and i don't know how to influence the constructor call by angular anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure how using ng-bind-html could help unless i generate all the html myself.

Comment: I thought you could generate tags and attributes at runtime that lead to the behavior you wanted. Maybe you could provide a more concrete example what you want to achieve. My Angular knowledge an the imagination about what one might do with is is still very limited :-|

Comment: I added an **edit** in the startpost to explain why i want to use a component